# Converting word dialog to VB

Tags: vba, printing, vb6, vbe

It has been a long time since doing any type of coding. 
I've been tasked to send a test page (looks like old TV test pattern page) to all of our printers prior to shift start.  These pages will help our team determine if there is any physical issues with the printers (bad toner, fuser, etc)
I have found this code and used in a VBA (MS Word).

```
 Sub Sorterprint01()
Dim sPrinter As String
Dim sPrinter1 As String
With Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrintSetup)
sPrinter = .Printer
.Printer = "\\dc999nt09\USPRT_01"
.DoNotSetAsSysDefault = True
.Execute
Application.PrintOut FileName = "\\dc999file\share\7yr\Support\IS_TEAM_LOCAL\TEST SHEETS\BARCODE TEST SORTER01.docx"
.Printer = sPrinter
.Execute
End With

End Sub
```

I even created a form to print to all or just a specific printer.
Management does NOT want this in a word doc and would prefer to have this in a VB app (even better would be web based).
After extensive research I have found that wdDialogFilePrintSetup is a WORD based dialog and does not work in VB6/2008/2013).  I am just getting back into coding and need a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use Automation. If you want to print docx files then you'll need word.

```
Set word = CreateObject("Word.Application")

With Word.dialogs(wdDialogFilePrintSetup)
```

etc. Just preface your objects with `word.`.

If using VBScript (which can't access constants - nor can VB6 if you don't add Word as a Reference) you need to specify the actual number that wdDialogFilePrintSetup is equal to.

So

```
With Word.dialogs(97)
```